# PHP - Update password page

Tags: php, sql, passwords

I'm attempting to create a page whereby users are able to change their password, but having trouble with my sql statment, can someone tell me where i'm going wrong? here's the code;

```
<?php
  session_start();

  include_once("home_start.php");
  require_once("functions.php");   
  require_once("db_connect.php");

  $submit = trim($_POST['submit']); 
  $username = trim($_POST['username']);
  $password = trim($_POST['password']); 
  $newpassword = trim($_POST['newpassword']);     
  $repeatnewpassword = trim($_POST['repeatnewpassword']); 

  if ($username && $password){ 

    session_start(); 

    require_once("db_connect.php"); 

    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database) or die("Couldn't find db"); 

    $username = clean_string($db_server, $username); 
    $password = clean_string($db_server, $password); 
    $pass = $_POST[‘password’]; 

    $salt = "$salt1$string$salt2"; 
    $hashpass = md5($pass . $salt);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 

    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
      $db_username = $row['username']; 
      $db_password = $row['password']; 
      if($username==$db_username && salt($password)==$db_password){    
        $_SESSION['username']=$username; 
        $_SESSION['logged']="logged"; 
        $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='$newpassword' WHERE       
  username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
      } else {
        $message = "<h1>Incorrect password!</h1>";
      }

      mysqli_free_result($result); 
      require_once("db_close.php"); 

    } else { 
      $message = "<h1>Please enter a valid username/password</h1>"; 
    } 

     //home_start/end only required if submitting to a separate page 

    //include_once("home_start.php"); 

    echo $message; 

  }
?>

<h1>Change Password</h1> 

<form id="register" action='password.php' method='POST'>   
  Username: <input type='text' name='username'><br /> 
  Current Password: <input type='password' name='password'><br /> 
  New Password: <input type='password' name='newpassword'><br /> 
  Repeat New Password: <input type='password' name='repeatnewpassword'><br /> 

  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'> <br /> 

</form>

<?php include_once("home_close.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Could you add a more descriptive problem description than "having trouble with my sql statement"?

Comment: i'm not sure the sql statement that i'm inputting is correct. I get the error message "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cs12jcw/public_html/home_start.php:29) in /home/cs12jcw/public_html/password.php on line 56" 

my sql statment is on line 56

Comment: You're trying to insert the password plaintext into the DB when this code is using hash and salt functions.  Also you never check if $newpassword and $repeatnewpassword match. I would work on understanding the existing code before attempting this.

Comment: You're also using a mysql_query in mysqli_* code. And you never make a call to execute the query.

Comment: Check if you don't have multiples call to session_start(). For exemple, if you have a call to session_start() in "home_close.php", you'll have the error you mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

When you are comparing the password for verification, I found that you have used salt over your given password. Which means you have already a salted(or encrypted) password in db.

```
salt($password)==$db_password
```

But when you are storing the new password in to db, I didn't see you encrypt(or salt) on it.

```
UPDATE users SET password='$newpassword'...
```

So, when you are doing login using the new password, you'll never get it matched!